# Ionic 2, Angular 2 & Auth0 Implementation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, oauth

I'm currently attempting to start a project but i'm having major issues with the implementation of Auth0 into an Angular 2, Ionic 2 project.

I'm unable to get the Ionic 2 quick start to work with all the correct installs, where as the Angular 2 project is easy to get working.

I was wondering if anyone had any information to whether this is possible, i assume so, and if there's a quick start which implements the latest versions of angular & ionic with Auth0 authentication.

Comment: Can you be explicit to what tutorials you already tried?

Comment: There is a serious lack of docs about how to get Ionic 2 and Auth0 to play with each other now that Ionic had the 2.0 release, and Auth0 moved to V8 of their library. I have been searching hard but just can't find much about how these two are supposed to work together.